# Restrict number of clients to ktor server

Tags: websocket, netty, ktor

I am creating a Ktor server for wss that I am running on my VPS.
I would like to control the number of clients that can connect to it in my engine config.
How do I do this for a netty or CIO engine?
I do not want to handle this in my code by using user ids because that would add unnecessary checks in my while loop, and would go this way only if its not possible to control this in the engine config.

Comment: You can use the `RateLimit` plugin to restrict the number of clients. You can find more info in the documentation https://ktor.io/docs/rate-limit.html.

Comment: Can you please add as answer so that I will mark it as correct asnwer? Is there a standard way how to use it for a REST type server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RateLimit](https://ktor.io/docs/rate-limit.html) plugin to limit the number of requests a client can make within a specific period. Also, there is a [sample project](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/2.3.2/codeSnippets/snippets/rate-limit) which shows its usage.

Comment: Can this plugin be used to defend brute force attack? Like I would maintain a list of all client IPs and maintain a count of how many times an IP is connecting and then block an IP when the rate limiter bucket becomes 0?

Comment: You can implement the `RateLimiter` interface to have a rate limiter with the necessary logic.